# asp.net MVC: binary deployment of mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can I deploy an mvc application, without publishing the aspx view files. Is there a way to publish the generated dll assemblies?

In the project file is an option "MvcBuildViews", which builds these dll files. But they are build in a temp directory and not used in the publishment process. Is there a way to include these files?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would build them into an assembly as embedded resources, then write a custom View Factory to get them.